# What's the difference between CREATE PROC and CREATE PROCEDURE?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've scoured [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) and haven't found an answer. Is there a difference I should know about?

If there is truly no difference then why would this redundancy exist?

```
--SQL Server Stored Procedure Syntax
CREATE { PROC | PROCEDURE } [schema_name.] procedure_name [ ; number ] 
    [ { @parameter [ type_schema_name. ] data_type }
        [ VARYING ] [ = default ] [ OUT | OUTPUT | [READONLY]
    ] [ ,...n ] 
[ WITH <procedure_option> [ ,...n ] ]
[ FOR REPLICATION ] 
AS { [ BEGIN ] sql_statement [;] [ ...n ] [ END ] }
[;]
```

Same with DROP PROC

```
DROP { PROC | PROCEDURE } { [ schema_name. ] procedure } [ ,...n ]
```

Comment: One is just the short hand for the other. No differences at all.

Comment: The grammar you've posted explains. `{ PROC | PROCEDURE }` should be read as `PROC or PROCEDURE` - the vertical pipe means OR.

Comment: @KenWhite That I knew. I just wanted to know **if** there was a difference and why the potentially unnecessary doubleness.

Comment: If you understood that it was OR, then it should be clear to you that they're the same thing (which is why I presumed you didn't and explained). It's not a *redundancy*, either; it's simply a shorthand versus long equivalent.

Comment: The syntax indicates that either is supported and there is no semantic difference explained in the documentation, hence you are left to assume that there is no difference. (When there is a semantic difference, e.g. `[ NULL | NOT NULL ]`, it will be explained in the documentation.) It may simply be offered for compatibility with an ancient version of the product. I've not found evidence that it is required by the ISO/IEC standard. (Note that there appears to be an error in the syntax. I believe it should be `[ OUT | OUTPUT ] [READONLY]`.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no difference between the two.

**Edit to answer your new question** - there is no "redundancy" here, one is just short hand for the other. "Procedure" is a fairly long word, and people tend to like shortcuts for things. In the same way, "Exec" and "Execute" are the same.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Barranka err... Yes, it does.